# error: data must be a string or Buffer and salt must either be a salt string or a number of rounds

Tags: postgresql, express

i'm using bcrypt to hash the password but when i use postman to the test the api it gives me this error : data must be a string or Buffer and salt must either be a salt string or a number of  rounds
here is my code

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const pool = require('../utils/db')
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')

router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {

    try {
        const { username, email, password } = req.body
        const user = await pool.query('select * from users where email = $1', [
            email
        ])
        if (user.rows.length !== 0) {
            return res.status(401).send('user already exists')
        }
        const saltRounds = 10;
        const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(saltRounds)

        const bcryptPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password,salt)
        const newUser = pool.query('insert into users(username,password,email) values ($1,$2,$3)', [username, bcryptPassword, email])
        jwt.sign({user}, 'secretkey', { expiresIn: '30s' }, (err, token) => {
            res.json({
              token
            });
          });


    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }

})
```

Answer (score 1):

I converted my number password to string and solved my problem.

```
const passwordToString = password.toString()
const passwordHash = await bcrypt.hash(passwordToString, salt);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple. Just use:
let bcryptPassword = bcrypt.hash(password,parseInt(salt));